# Can't select form with python using mechanize

Tags: python, forms, mechanize-python

I'm trying to select a form with python, but it isn't working.

The page i am working with is: http://www.safilonet.safilo.com/

```
def login(self):
    url = self._baseUrl + '/webapp/commerce/safilo/jsp/logon.jsp'
    self._br.open(url, timeout=30.0)
    self._br.select_form('logon')   
    self._br.form['login'] = self._username
    self._br.form['password'] = self._password
    self._br.submit()
```

The error presented is:

```
File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 524, in select_form
mechanize._mechanize.FormNotFoundError: no form matching name 'logon'
```

Can you please help me? 
Thanks

Comment: What framework are you working with?

Comment: @lzkata: The error message shows that it is [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/).

Comment: Well, for one thing /webapp/commerce/safilo/jsp/logon.jsp on that site doesn't appear to have any forms at all on it...

Comment: Change `select_form('logon')` to `select_form(name='logon')`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski it didn't work... :S I can't understand what is wrong with this...

Comment: @Wooble the form "logon" is included on the frame whose src is  /webapp/commerce/safilo/jsp/logon.jsp...

Comment: Well, mechanize and my browser's View Source function disagree with you, but clearly you know better.

Comment: @Wooble you can see that there's a frame `<frame name="doc" src="/webapp/commerce/safilo/jsp/logon.jsp?lng=E&amp;cpy=10" scrolling="auto" margiheight="0" marginwidth="0">`. Inside this frame is the form `logon`. Right?